# How to use Chrome javascript event listener?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome, listener, inspect

Chrome inspect element event listener can be very useful to see what event listeners are on a dom element.
However, when unfolded, there is no "human exploitable" data...

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/152/screenshot20120510at145.png/

Is there any way to have more info about the event listener ? like the js file/ line number it is in ?

Comment: I don't believe this is scripatable from JavaScript. You'd need a plug-in.